# Magento 2.3.X : Display error message when user add more products to cart than the stock quantity in

Tags: magento2.3, addtocart, simple-product, stock-availability

Thank you for reading my question.

I am working on a Magento 2.3 version and facing an issue which is

> When I add the product to cart more than the available stock it doesn't show the error message. Like if the user wants to add 25 products to cart and the stock has only 23, as a result, this should show error message to the user telling there's just 23 pcs of this item and give two options add (the 23) or erase product from cart Can you help me to fix this issue?

Here goes the list of Installed modules:[image]

Looking forward to hearing from your great experience.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is default feature of the Magento. But you can use a plugin for your requirement before the product added to the cart to check.

Comment: reference link = > https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/show-stock-remaining-items.html

Answer (score 1):

To show error message when user tries to add a product to cart with quantity higher than current product's available quantity, you can disable the backorder (simply by setting the `Backorders` value to `No Backorders` in current product's advanced quantity).

1. Set the `Backorders` value to `No Backorders`
   [image]
2. Error message appears like this if you try to add a product to cart with quantity higher than current product's available quantity
   [image]

Comment: Hi Randy, thanks for the answer. I checked and it's already set to No Backorders. Success message is working perfect but error message is not being displayed :(

Comment: one of your installed modules probably change this behavior, did you check it? could you please add list of installed modules in your question?

Comment: Sure. Let me add

Comment: I have added the list of enabled modules. I will be really grateful if you could spare 5 mints to check this thing. Link: https://www.fulloffice.com.mx/fo/repuesto-para-z-mulsion-tinta-negrepuesto-punto-mediano-1-0mm-1pza-zeb-rep-0602-00.html#

Comment: I could not add any products to cart, I got javascript error `blocked:mixed-content` after clicking the `add to cart` button. See https://imgur.com/MpZ1s8l

Comment: I was working on it and trying to find a way may that's why you find it not working. Can you please try now. I will be really grateful.

Comment: This is going to be a long way. If you want to proceed, execute `bin/magento --version` and `composer info magento/module-inventory-sales`, then update your question with result of those commands. Also add the content of `vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition/IsSalableWithReservationsCondition.php` file to your question.